# Como listar todos Browsers instalados no Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como faço para listar/verificar todos os browsers instalados em um dispositivo Android via Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É impossível saber/determinar quais aplicações são do tipo Browser, pelo simples motivo que não há nenhum identificador informando isso para o Android. Também é muito arriscado você procurar todos os packages que possuem `browser` por exemplo.

Uma sugestão é que, você pode listar, por exemplo, quais `Activity`'s conseguem abrir uma determinada `Intent` com uma URL:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
List<ResolveInfo> list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
        PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        for (ResolveInfo info : list) {
            String name = info.name;
        }
```

Comment: Boa ideia @sicachester! Mas uma dúvida, qual é o tipo do context?

Comment: Sua `Activity` já é um `Context`, veja aqui http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. No caso, dentro de sua `Activity`, só utilize `getPackageManager()`, sem `context`